# Client-Server IPs on different networks

Tags: sockets, ip, client-server

Let's say I create a client-server app. Server: Swing app --client: swing app, server: swing app -- client: android app...Whatever. The general idea is: server listens to a certain port, you make a connection through sockets(set the server's IP address into client app ) and you transfer the message from client to server, etc etc... That's OK if client and server are on the same network. But if client is on a different network, how to specify server's IP address???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the client and server are on different networks (the most common situation being the client connecting to the server through the Internet), there has to be routers in between network so they can talk to each other.  If the server is being a NAT, you connect to the NAT's public IP, then the NAT connects to the server.  If the NAT is itself behind another NAT, you use that NAT's public IP, which then connects to the NAT that the server is connected to.  And so on.  In other words, you won't know the server's private LAN IP, nor do you need to.  You use its public WAN IP instead.  Or, you use whatever public IP the server's hostname resolves to in a DNS lookup, if it has a hostname assigned.